# countDowntimer not Resetting for a new Value and shows the old value always

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to show a countDownTimer in my activity. the value I am using in the countDowntimer is coming from a recyclerview of another activity using bundle. when I click one of the recyclerview time for the first time, the countDownTimer shows the time running perfectly. but when I select another time, the old instance continues to run. I have implemented the cancel and onFinish() methods to but they are not working as I want. I searched everywhere but everyone suggested about cancel and onFinish() methods. I am unable to find a solution now.

```
public void getData() {
    if(countDownTimer!=null){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    if (replaceTime != null) {
        time = Integer.parseInt(replaceTime);
    } else
        Toast.makeText(FullTimerActivity.this, "",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = time;

    timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;


    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

            if (leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds) {
                if (blink) {
                    // mTextField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // if blink is true, textview will be visible
                } else {
                    //   mTextField.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                blink = !blink;
            }

            String a = String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60);
            textView.setText(a);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(FullTimerActivity.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to know what went wrong without seeing more code. I suggest you set logs for time and the if condition. That should give you an idea.

Comment: let me see it..

Answer (score 0):

In onFinish()  also set the text to TextView like below

```
textView.setText("0");
```